# How can I beat Trap Adventure 2?

Tags: trap-adventure-2

I have tried playing through [Trap Adventure 2](http://hudgames.com/game/trap-adventure-2) many times, but I can't beat it! If anyone has any advice on how to beat the game, please let me know!

Answer (score 1):

This game is all about precision, and memory. Every trap is exactly the same, so it's just about remembering what trap is next, where it is, and what/when it triggers.

There are videos [like this one](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a9esk9m9PqQ) that are complete run throughs of the game, however there is no specific "guides" that I have found, as this is designed to be difficult.

Basically, the way to beat the game is "practice".